# the use of windows completion port in named pipe

Tags: c++, winapi, ipc, named-pipes, io-completion-ports

I need to transfer data between processes, I have a local server process and multiple clients process, they may send data and receive data at the same time.I create the namedpipe and `CreateIoCompletionPort` in server. And when the client `CreateFile` , the `GetQueuedCompletionStatus` will return which is what I expect, however, when the client writefile, the server cannot get Completion port package, I want the server to be notified when client come , out and send message, how should I do?

I know a little about the `PostQueuedCompletionStatus` function which can notify the completion port but I cannot get the Completion port handle in client process, could anyone tell me the common implementation, thanks!

Comment: when client write to file - server read will be completed (server must permanent read after connect). you not need notify about client operation complete from server. you need only your own io complete notify

Comment: and in most case you not need create completion port yourself, call GetQueuedCompletionStatus etc. instead bind callback to file handle via BindIoCompletionCallback